# How do I show a relation between two or more cells, so that I afterwards can make pivot table and show how many connection I have

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long spreadsheet with names and family relationship. I want a way to show that a group of people are connected as family, so that I can create a pivot table to see how many families we are providing housing for, and how large the famlies are.

Backstory: I have a long list of around a thousand refugees that need housing. I have empty apartments of different sizes, so I want a way to look up families in a way so that the family show up together in the spreadsheet.

English is not my first language so I'll provide more information if the above don't make sense.

Sincerely

Comment: Welcome! One way is to appoint one of them as the "head of the family." This can be either the oldest member of the family, or the most active (with whom you agree on accommodation), or you can choose any other criterion. In the help column, label each row with the name of this "main family member" (you can use the Data-Validation drop-down list for this). In the case that a very large family has to settle in two or more rooms, add the address of the apartment to the name. So you will have a more or less reliable sign for combining records into groups. And yes, thank you for what you do!

Comment: Is it possible to create a unique identifier for each famliy, listing them in a separate sheet.,in person sheet, write the unique identifier of their family? Then you use them create a [PowerPivot table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed).

Comment: It would be useful if you could add a sample spreadsheet to the question, showing how the family relationship is represented in the sheet.